# How to print string version of backspace in python?

Tags: python, string

How would I print '\x08' as '\x08' in python? If I enter the command

```
print '\x08'
```

the output is blank instead of

```
\x08
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please use `r` before string, it means *raw string*, in which you don't need to escape special chars. For more details about string literal prefixes please read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings).

```
print r'\x08'
```

Comment: yeah but the string is stored in a variable (i.e. s = '\x08'), how do I print the raw variable?

Comment: nvm i found out that i can use .format and format the string variable as a raw string

Answer (score 1):

You can just escape `'\x08'` (backspace character) by doing,

```
print '\\x08'
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can also do `print repr(c).strip("'")`, where c is the string you want to view in the code format, ie TAB will show as '\t' and newline as '\n' and so on..